# How do I download the latest version of Heartpy==1.2.4

Tags: python-3.x

I'm doing analysing of a Noisy ECG signal using Heartpy but when I run the code below in the respiratory examples I'm getting this Error:

AttributeError: module 'HeartPy' has no attribute 'enhance_ecg_peaks'

I have downloaded heartpy using

1-pip install heartpy==1.2.4

2-pip install heartpy

3-I have downloaded the respiratory:https://github.com/paulvangentcom/heartrate_analysis_python.git

4-I have clone it

```py
filtered = hp.enhance_ecg_peaks(hp.scale_data(ecg), sample_rate, 
                 iterations=4, aggregation='median', notch_filter=True)


#show filtered signal

plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))

plt.plot(filtered)

plt.show()

#zoom in on signal section and overlay filtered segment 

plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))

plt.title('original signal zoom in')

plt.plot(hp.scale_data(ecg[15000:17000]), label='original data')

plt.title('processed signal zoom in')

plt.plot(hp.scale_data(filtered[15000:17000]), alpha=0.5, label='processed 
                      data')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the entire documentation for [Python Heart Rate Analysis Toolkit
Documentation](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/python-heart-rate-analysis-toolkit/latest/python-heart-rate-analysis-toolkit.pdf)

enhance_ecg_peaks : [heartpy.enhance_ecg_peaks(hrdata, sample_rate, iterations=4, aggregation='mean', notch_filter=True)](https://python-heart-rate-analysis-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/heartpy.heartpy.html#heartpy.enhance_ecg_peaks)

It has been a bug and an issue is created [heartrate_analysis_python ->  attribute missing](https://github.com/paulvangentcom/heartrate_analysis_python/issues/35)

**Steps to fix** :

1. Uninstall the existing `heartpy` using

   `pip uninstall heartpy==1.2.4`
2. Clone the repository of `heartpy` and run the setup

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/paulvangentcom/heartrate_analysis_python.git
   cd heartrate_analysis_python
   python -m setup.py install
   ```

Then you can simply use and it works just fine:

```
filtered = hp.enhance_ecg_peaks(hp.scale_data(ecg), sample_rate, 
             iterations=4, aggregation='median', notch_filter=True)
```

Hope this will help you.